# MDX: How to get the weeks between two dates in MDX Query

Tags: date, tfs, mdx, olap-cube

I want to get the weeks as columns between two dates in an MDX query.

For example if I input these dates: **2015-01-01** and **2015-02-01** I want to get this:

**Week ending January 1,Week ending January 8,Week ending January 15,Week ending January 22**

I have created this MDX query with "Filter" method but it doesn't work:

```
    WITH SET [WeeksBetweenDates] AS

Filter([Date].[Year - Week - Date Hierarchy].[Week],
[Date].[Year - Week - Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Member_Value >= [Date].[Year - Week - Date Hierarchy].[Week].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]
AND [Date].[Year - Week - Date Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Member_Value <= [Date].[Year - Week - Date Hierarchy].[Week].&[2015-02-01T00:00:00])

SELECT [WeeksBetweenDates] ON COLUMNS
FROM [Team System]
```

I get "**Unknown**" column if I run this query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should define dates as subcube slice (`{[Date1] : [Date2]}`), this will greatly increase query performance + make code more transparent (tested against our TFS):

```
select
{
    [Date].[Week].members
} on 0
from ( select {
               [Date].[Date].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]
               :
               [Date].[Date].&[2015-02-01T00:00:00]
              } on 0
from [Team System])
```

To make it work through using hierarchy, you should correct
`[Date].[Year - Week - Date Hierarchy].[Week].&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]` to [Date].[Year - Week - Date Hierarchy].**[Date]**.&[2015-01-01T00:00:00]

Comment: Thanks for your comment but this query also doesn't work. I get 0 columns if I run the query. :(

Comment: @konzolcowboy an important note is that if either dates in `{[Date1] : [Date2]}` do not exist in your cube then it will be evaluated as null by the engine, effectively like this `{null : [Date2]}`... this will then be evaluated as open ended i.e. all dates upto `[Date2]`